# mysql ST_Intersect is slow

Tags: mysql, gis, spatial

I have two tables. Table-1 contains points and table-2 contains polygons (These are neighborhoods) I used the query below to find points from table-1 inside a specific neighborhood in table-1. For example, the neighborhood below is "Bayview Hunters Point" The query runs and and returns data back but it takes quite a long time (25 seconds) There is 1000 records in table-1 and 20 records in table-2

I found online that giving your column a spatial index helps. I did all of that but it is still slow. Does anyone have any suggestions?

```
select * from quarter_data as QD,

(select * from planning_area where planarea = 'Bayview Hunters Point') as PA

where ST_Intersects(QD.point_geometry, PA.geo_coordinates);
```

Comment: What version of MySQL are you using?  They started using the Boost.Geometry libraries in 5.7 which are much more efficient and updated in 8.0

Comment: hello, thank you for your comment. I believe i was using the newest version. I ended up using postgres instead of mysql and it worked fine. It seems like postgres has an extension postGIS that works for dealing with spatial data.